# What does the rake task db:full_reset do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, capistrano, bundler, rake-task

I have the following in my deploy script in which I inherited from other devs. Does any one know what the rake task db:full_reset does? I would think it resets the db but I can't find that actual task anywhere in the code. Running `rake -T` doesn't give any clues. Would it be located in a gem?

```
namespace :db do
  task :full_reset do
    on roles(:app) do
      within release_path do
        with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
          execute :bundle, "exec rake db:full_reset"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rake -W db:full_reset` to see where that task is defined

Comment: It is defined ... no where! I hate code that just sits in the codebase and doesn't do anything.